# error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'core' with no type

Tags: c++

I am getting error in the title. First of all, I did my search here in stackoverflow and in the google. There are many similar errors but I couldn't figure out how to solve the error. Some of the errors that I am getting with the error in the title are below. There are way many errors than the below errors but I just put a few of them.

```
    core.cpp:9:102: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'core' with no type [-fpermissive]
    uint32_t number_of_core_msg_types, uint32_t msg_q_size, uint32_t bytes_per_flit) throw(err) :

    core.cpp:9:102: error: 'int boost::core::core(const pe_id&, const uint64_t&, boost::shared_ptr<id_factory<long long unsigned int> >, boost::shared_ptr<tile_statistics>, logger&, boost::shared_ptr<random_gen>, boost::shared_ptr<memory>, uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t)' should have been declared inside 'boost::core'

    core.cpp: In function 'int boost::core::core(const pe_id&, const uint64_t&, boost::shared_ptr<id_factory<long long unsigned int> >, boost::shared_ptr<tile_statistics>, logger&, boost::shared_ptr<random_gen>, boost::shared_ptr<memory>, uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t)':

    core.cpp:10:5: error: only constructors take member initializers
 pe(id), system_time(t), stats(st), log(l), ran(r),
```

Here is my core.hpp file:

```
    #ifndef __CORE_HPP__
    #define __CORE_HPP__

    #include <vector>
    #include <map>
    #include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
    #include <boost/bind.hpp>
    #include "id_factory.hpp"
    #include "logger.hpp"
    #include "statistics.hpp"
    #include "pe.hpp"
    #include "random.hpp"
    #include "bridge.hpp"
    #include "messages.hpp"
    #include "memory.hpp"

    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost;

   /* core class provides common constructor process and connect process */

    #define MAX_PAYLOAD 256

    class core : public pe {
    public:
           core(const pe_id &id, const uint64_t &system_time,
               shared_ptr<id_factory<packet_id> > packet_id_factory,
               shared_ptr<tile_statistics> stats, logger &log,
               shared_ptr<random_gen> ran,
               shared_ptr<memory> mem,
               uint32_t number_of_core_msg_types, 
               uint32_t msg_queue_size, uint32_t m_bytes_per_flit) throw(err);
     virtual ~core() throw();

     /* Common core methods */
     virtual void connect(shared_ptr<bridge> net_bridge) throw(err);
     virtual void tick_positive_edge() throw(err);
     virtual void tick_negative_edge() throw(err);

    /* Fast forwarding */
    virtual uint64_t next_pkt_time() throw(err);
    virtual bool is_drained() const throw() = 0;

    /* not used */
    virtual void add_packet(uint64_t time, const flow_id &flow, uint32_t len) throw(err);
    virtual bool work_queued() throw(err);
    virtual bool is_ready_to_offer() throw(err);
    virtual void set_stop_darsim() throw(err);

    protected:
    /* implement core logic */
    virtual void execute() = 0;
    /* check and update finished memory requests */
    virtual void update_from_memory_requests() = 0;

    void tick_positive_edge_memory() throw(err);
    void tick_negative_edge_memory() throw(err);

    /* use these queues to use the network */
    shared_ptr<messageQueue> receive_queue(uint32_t type);
    shared_ptr<messageQueue> send_queue(uint32_t type);

    /* Global time */
    const uint64_t &system_time;

    /* Aux */
    shared_ptr<tile_statistics> stats;
    logger &log;
    shared_ptr<random_gen> ran;

    uint32_t m_number_of_msg_types;
    uint32_t m_first_core_msg_type;
    uint32_t m_msg_queue_size;
    uint32_t m_bytes_per_flit;

    /* memory */
    shared_ptr<memory> m_memory;

    private:
    typedef struct {
         packet_id id;
         flow_id flow;
         uint32_t len;
         uint32_t xmit;
         uint64_t payload[MAX_PAYLOAD];
    } core_incoming_packet_t;
    typedef map<uint32_t, core_incoming_packet_t> incoming_packets_t;

    void release_xmit_buffer();

    map<uint32_t/*msg type*/, shared_ptr<messageQueue> > m_out_msg_queues;
    map<uint32_t/*msg type*/, shared_ptr<messageQueue> > m_in_msg_queues;

    /* Network */
    shared_ptr<bridge> m_net;
    vector<uint32_t> m_queue_ids;
    incoming_packets_t m_incoming_packets;
    shared_ptr<id_factory<packet_id> > m_packet_id_factory;
    map<uint32_t, uint64_t*> m_xmit_buffer;

    uint32_t m_receive_channel_round_robin_pointer;
    uint32_t m_send_queue_round_robin_pointer;

    };

    #endif
```

and here is relevant part of the core.cpp file:

```
#include "core.hpp"

core::core(const pe_id &id, const uint64_t &t, shared_ptr<id_factory<packet_id> > pif,
       shared_ptr<tile_statistics> st, logger &l, shared_ptr<random_gen> r,
       shared_ptr<memory> mem,
       uint32_t number_of_core_msg_types, uint32_t msg_q_size, uint32_t bytes_per_flit) throw(err) :
pe(id), system_time(t), stats(st), log(l), ran(r),
m_msg_queue_size(msg_q_size), m_bytes_per_flit(bytes_per_flit), m_memory(mem), m_packet_id_factory(pif),
m_receive_channel_round_robin_pointer(0), m_send_queue_round_robin_pointer(0)
{
       m_number_of_msg_types = number_of_core_msg_types + mem->number_of_mem_msg_types();
       m_first_core_msg_type = mem->number_of_mem_msg_types();
       for (uint32_t i = 0; i < m_number_of_msg_types; ++i) {
              m_in_msg_queues[i] = shared_ptr<messageQueue> (new messageQueue(i, m_msg_queue_size));
              m_out_msg_queues[i] = shared_ptr<messageQueue> (new messageQueue(i, m_msg_queue_size));
       }
       m_memory->set_core_send_queues(m_out_msg_queues);
       m_memory->set_core_receive_queues(m_in_msg_queues);
 }

core::~core() throw() { }

void core::connect(shared_ptr<bridge> net_bridge) throw(err) {
    m_net = net_bridge;
    shared_ptr<vector<uint32_t> > qs = m_net->get_ingress_queue_ids();
    m_queue_ids.clear();
    copy(qs->begin(), qs->end(), back_insert_iterator<vector<uint32_t> >(m_queue_ids));
}

shared_ptr<messageQueue> core::receive_queue(uint32_t type) {
    assert((uint32_t)type < m_number_of_msg_types);
    return m_in_msg_queues[type];
}

shared_ptr<messageQueue> core::send_queue(uint32_t type) {
    assert((uint32_t)type < m_number_of_msg_types);
    return m_out_msg_queues[type];
}

void core::release_xmit_buffer() {
/* release xmit buffer for injection if transmission is done */
    for (map<uint32_t, uint64_t*>::iterator i = m_xmit_buffer.begin(); i != m_xmit_buffer.end(); ++i) {
        if (m_net->get_transmission_done(i->first)) {
            delete[] i->second;
            m_xmit_buffer.erase(i->first);
            break;
        }
    }
}
.......
.......
.......
```

Can anyone point out what the problem is? By the way, I am trying to compile a program and these codes are the parts of the program.

Comment: From the error message, it appears that you are getting `boost::core` into scope. Remove `using namespace boost;` to see if the problem will go away. Use `boost` explicitly where you need to.

Comment: Try removing `using namespace boost;` and prefix anything used from `boost::` explicitly.

Comment: Notice that it is complaining about `'int boost::core::core`. This should have struck you as strange, because your class is `core::core` in global namespace, not in the boost namespace. That's your foot in the door to converting the error message into understanding what the problem is. (This is how the other commenters came to the conclusion that you are conflicting with `boost::core`.)

Comment: `using namespace` strikes again! Can no one stop this evil fiend?

Comment: Thanks guys. Problem was the scope. I didn't remove the boost namespace but solved the problem.